# Updating a cell's accessory in edit mode

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a fairly commonplace grouped `UITableView` that allows a user to select a department. When they select a row, I update the accessory view to display a checkmark on the new row and remove it from the previous row.

I also allow editing of the table view. In edit mode, the checkmarks are hidden, which is fine. But if the user deletes the row for the currently selected (checked) department, I need to programmatically move the checkmark.

I have tried using the same approach that I use to add and remove the checkmarks when a new department is used:

```
- (void)deleteDepartmentAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    //if the current item is using the deleted department, move the checkmark
    Department *dept = [self.departments objectAtIndex:index];
    if (self.item.department == dept)
    {
        UITableViewCell *noneCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.departments.count inSection:0]];
        noneCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.departments.count inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }

    //delete the department and save
    [dept.managedObjectContext deleteObject:dept];

    //delete the row
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

But when the table view exists edit mode, no row has the checkmark accessory. I have even tried manually reloading the row whilst still in edit mode (as seen in the code above).

How can I make sure that the row's accessory is refreshed when the table view exits edit mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `accessoryType` for non-edit mode and use `editingAccessoryType` for edit mode. This way you don't have to clear the checkmark or restore the checkmark going in and out of editing mode. Set the `editingAccessoryType` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`.

And of course you need to make sure that your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` always sets the proper `accessoryType` for each row.

Edit:

Overriding `setEditing:animated:` will allow you to reload the checked row (if visible) when leaving edit mode.

Comment: I'm already doing this. I'm trying to update the accessory type when the table view comes out of editing. The department is deleted, so the check mark should move to the 'none' row. I'm also updating the data source such that the cell should set the correct accessory after the deletion, only it doesn't get refreshed.

Comment: Oh, and I can confirm that the accessory is indeed updated by scrolling the cell out of view and back in again. I suppose I need someway to tell the tableview to reload that row when coming out of edit mode?

Comment: Try overriding `setEditing:animated:` to reload the checked row (if visible) when leaving edit mode.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I have to pick whether or not to animate, which means either a fade in/out of the label, or no animation of the accessory, but since it's just a checkmark using no animation looks fine. Out of interest, why would you check if it is visible? Is that a performance thing?

Comment: There's no sense in reloading a cell that is off screen. In fact, this may actually cause an exception.

Comment: I guess. There's maybe a modicum of sense, if it simplifies the code without any side effects. But better safe than sorry I suppose. If you want to update your answer I will accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: THANK-YOU. After hours of fuffing around with all manner of alleged solutions, hacks and workarounds, stumbling across this answer was a godsend.